# inversion of keys and values from the original dictionary and ordering

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Can anyone tell me how I can get my code to produce the desired outputs below. Cheers

```
def dict_invert(d):
    inv = {}
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        keys = inv.setdefault(v, [])
        keys.append(k)
    return inv
```

---

my input1: `>>> dict_invert({30000: 30, 600: 30, 2: 10})`

my output1: `>>> {10: [2], 30: [30000, 600]}`
desired output1 `>>> {10: [2], 30: [600, 30000]}`

---

my input2: `>>> dict_invert({0: 9, 9: 9, 5: 9})`

my output2: `>>> {9: [0, 9, 5]}`

**desired output2: `>>> {9: [0, 5, 9]}`**

Comment: Please show us what have you tried

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to group the keys of the input dictionary into lists by the values of the input dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def dict_invert(d):
    dd = defaultdict(list)
    for k in d:
        dd[d[k]].append(k)
    return {k:sorted(dd[k]) for k in dd} 

>>> dict_invert({30000: 30, 600: 30, 2: 10})
{10: [2], 30: [600, 30000]}
>>> dict_invert({0: 9, 9: 9, 5: 9})
{9: [0, 5, 9]}
```

So, for these examples, this produces the output that you wanted. It's not clear whether you also want the resultant dictionary to be sorted by key. In the examples above, the keys appear sorted, but they are not really because a dictionary has no inherent order.

```
>>> dict_invert({30000: 30, 600: 30, 2: 10, 1234: -1})
{10: [2], 30: [600, 30000], -1: [1234]}
```

If you want the keys to be ordered take a look at [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

```
def dict_invert(d):
    dd = defaultdict(list)
    for k in d:
        dd[d[k]].append(k)
    return OrderedDict(sorted((k, sorted(dd[k])) for k in dd))

>>> dict_invert({30000: 30, 600: 30, 2: 10, 1234: -1})
OrderedDict([(-1, [1234]), (10, [2]), (30, [600, 30000])])
```

Comment: Alternatively replace `dd[d[k]].append(k)` with `bisect.insort(dd[d[k]], k)` and remove the calls to `sorted`.

Comment: @Bakuriu: yeah, I briefly thought about that but thought it might confuse. Plus I couldn't be bothered looking it up :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 function dict_invert(obj){

        var objArr = {};
        for(var key in obj){
            if(!objArr[obj[key]]){
                objArr[obj[key]] = [];

            }
            objArr[obj[key]].push(key);        
        }

        return objArr;

    }
    var objArr = dict_invert({30000: 30, 600: 30, 2: 10});
```